# JCL what is wrong with this?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I am trying to crack this `JCL` and wonder what is wrong.

This is my code :

```
 000001 //SORTJCL   JOB                                        
 000002 //SORTSTEP  EXEC PGM=SORT                              
 000003 //SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*                                
 000004 //SORTOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                
 000005 //SORTWK01  DD SPACE=(CYL,(1,1))                       
 000006 //SORTIN    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=Y2015.PUBLIC.DATA(AREACODE)
 000007 //SYSIN     DD *                                       
 000008   SORT FIELDS=(6,10,CH,A)                              
 000009 //  IF RC = 0 THEN                                     
 000010 //COPYSTEP  EXEC PGM=ICEGENER                          
 000011 //SYSUT1    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=Y2015.PUBLIC.DATA($005)    
 000012 //SYSUT2    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=&SYSUID..P2.OUTPUT($005)   
 000013 //SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*                                
 000014 //SYSPRINT  DD SYSOUT=*                                
 000015 //SYSIN     DD DUMMY                                   
 000016 //  ELSE                                               
 000017 //  ENDIF
```

The purpose of this code - to read and sort `Y2015.PUBLIC.DATA(AREACODE)` and copy and write the output into `MYID.P2.OUTPUT($005)`

Can anyone explain to me what am I missing?

Comment: Wow, it's been 30 years since I've seen JCL.  Can you describe what it does now?  (In other words, in what way is it not producing the output that you expect?)

Comment: You are SORTing to SYSOUT (the spool) and then copying (with ICEGENER) a totally different dataset to your expected output. Just change the SORTOUT DD to the dataset you require `DISP=SHR,DSN=&SYSUID..P2.OUTPUT($005)` and drop the entire ICEGENER step.

Answer (score 2):

To "***read and sort Y2015.PUBLIC.DATA(AREACODE)***", you already use the correct `//SORTIN` in your first jobstep, in line 000006. The result of that read and sort gets written to `//SORTOUT`, which in your JCL seems to be written to `SYSOUT=*` (the spool), in line 000003.

But that's NOT what you should do (as per your "***copy and write the output into MYID.P2.OUTPUT($005)***"). So therefor you must modify that line 000003 like so:

```
 000003 //SYSOUT    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=&SYSUID..P2.OUTPUT($005)
```

After you applied this change, you also have to remove everything related to the 2nd jobstep (so starting from line 000009 and everything following that line).

If for whatever reason you still want all those lines to continue to be included in this JCL, just insert a new line in front of line 000009 that looks like so:

```
 000009 //
```

This will cause all remaining JCL lines following it to just be ignored.

Comment: I'd agree with this :-)

Comment: Thank you Bill , by the way: whatever happened to the MFsite at area 51? A bit of a shame I think it didn't "make" it, no? Any chance we could give it some type of new try?